# UITableView and Another View inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have `UITableView` and `UIView`(used to show image slideshow) inside `UIScrollView`. The tableview is dynamic and i want to automatically adjust height of table view to show all the cells(and disable scrolling of tableview) and scrollview should show both slideshow and tableview and could be scrollable, I know how to do this with code but i want to know if is  possible to do in Interface builder(without using iOS6 auto layout) using previous(iOS5 and early) autoresize method in the xcode size inspecter tab(see image[image: old autoresizing method in xcode])

Comment: Why not try to Get your UIView (slideshow) inside the UITableView's cell (CustomCell)? It will simplify things.

Comment: I found much easier thing, i can drag a UIView to the UITableView header in IB,Then everything worked without a single line of code(and without additional scrollview except tableview itself) for adjust content sizes.If i change the frame of added UIView, UITableView automatically adjust the content size according to added view and Number of cells on the table

Answer (score 0):

I think this is hard to do only using interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your objects via interface builder. But for maintaing scrolling conditions you need to do it programmatically. Also for table view height to be dynamic you need to be done programmatically.